# prove rational $+$ irrational is irrational without contradiction.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

**Similar questions can be found on the web, mostly by contradiction, but I came up with this one, not sure if it sounds.**

Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ be fixed. Prove without contradiction: if $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\,$, then $x+y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

**attempt**

Equivatenly, if $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\,$ or $\,y\in\mathbb{Q}$.

we know $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ so it can't be in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, left to prove $y\in\mathbb{Q}$.
$$x+y=\frac{m}{n},x=\frac{p}{q}\implies y=\frac{mq-pn}{mq}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

Is this proof sound?

---

Appreciate anyone who has thought could leave the method on direct proof

Comment: No logical shenanigans if you want to prove directly. Assume $y$ is irrational and show $x+y$ is irrational.

Comment: Slight error: you can't assume $x\in\mathbb Q$, because you negated it when forming the contrapositive. It's a little more clear what to do if you express 
"$x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ or $y\in\mathbb Q$"
 as "if $y\in\mathbb Q$, then $x \in\mathbb Q$".

Comment: @FShrike Isn't *if  $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\,$, then $x+y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$* just the contrapositive? why is it wrong?

Comment: @FShrike It's proof by contrapositive, not by contradiction. And that statement is actually true. There's no counterexample.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you for your reply. Logically, how do you end up with $if y\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ from that one?

Comment: @LJNG "if A then B" is logically equivalent to "B or not A". To see this, note that the only way that "if A then B" can be false is if A is true and B is false. Therefore "if A then B" is equivalent to "not (A and not B)" = "B or not A".

Comment: @AlvinL I felt it is a trick too. But how do you do that by direct proof assuming one is rational another is irrational?

Comment: The contrapositive in OP is correct. The assumptions are $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $y\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @LJNG I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Then, I felt it should be *if $x\in \mathbb{Q}, then  y\in\mathbb{Q}$ *

Comment: @LJNG Ah, of course you are correct. Silly typos are the second biggest bane of mathematics, after escaping minus signs.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Hmm, I couldn’t parse their argument since the conclusion “x is irrational” threw me off. Besides, in the logic in which we are working here, proof by contrapositive is proof by contradiction in disguise.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Got any idea on the direct proof, assuming one is rational, another is irrational?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems right as far as I can see, but probably there are ways to express it more formally. I will try it.

As far as I can see the statement to be proved is

$$
\forall x,y(x\in \mathbb{Q}\,\land\, y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \implies x+y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\tag1
$$

Now, we have the following equivalences

$$
A\implies B\quad \text{ is logically equivalent to }\quad \lnot B \implies \lnot A\\
A\implies B\,\lor\, C\quad \text{ is logically equivalent to }\quad A\,\land\, \lnot B \implies C
$$

Using the first equivalence above gives a contrapositive statement, and the second equivalence above (unnamed as far as I know) is usually used without noticing it, its a metatheorem that can be proven using the inference rules of natural deduction.

Then applying the first equivalence to (1) gives

$$
\forall x,y(x+y\in \mathbb{Q}\implies x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \,\lor\, y\in \mathbb{Q})\tag2
$$

and as I dont see a clear way to give a direct proof from (2) I will use the second equivalence in (2) what gives

$$
\forall x,y(x+y\in \mathbb{Q}\,\land\, x\in \mathbb{Q}\implies y\in \mathbb{Q})\tag3
$$

Now (3) is very easy to prove using representations $x+y=\frac{r_1}{r_2}$ and $x=\frac{s_1}{s_2}$ for $s_1,r_1\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r_2,s_2\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, then we arrive to

$$
y=(x+y)-x=\frac{r_1}{r_2}-\frac{s_1}{s_2}=\frac{r_1s_2-s_1r_2}{s_2r_2}
$$

so we conclude that $y\in \mathbb{Q}$ as both, numerator and denominator of the last expression are integers and $s_2r_2>0$.∎

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why can't I just let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ as part of the antecedent

Comment: that contradiction should be $\neg A\land B\implies \bot$

Comment: Could you show me direct proof, by assuming $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational?

Comment: you are right about that contradicition!

Comment: @LJNG I've re-written my answer to something more formal and clear